# Avoiding an object reference not set to an object

Tags: c#, razor

i have a webpage i have been working on, where are forms for adding posts located.
The form has a filepicker for images
Problem is that when i click the button without an image selected, it gives me an error.
I have tried to dodge the error with Try{} Catch{}and with classic if statements.

```
var formFile = fileUpload.FormFile;
var filePath = Path.Combine(fullPath, formFile.FileName);
var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath);

db.VytvoritPrispevekOnas(nazevPrispevku, textPrispevku,"/OnasImages/",formFile.FileName.ToString());

formFile.CopyTo(stream);

stream.Close();
```

the error comes from the "var filepath" where it doesnt have any object saved in "formFile" to get the "formFile.FileName.
The thing is that the "var formFile" is not null, or an empty string or anything
Is there a chance to avoid that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: formFile has to be something. What happens when you debug?  The null reference is coming from somewhere..

Comment: Also you say you have used try/catch and if statements. But there are none in the code you posted

Comment: _"when i click the button without an image selected"_ - there you go. It's an UX problem: The button should not be enabled as long as there is no image selected in the first place.

Comment: I completely agree with @Fildor. This should be blocked by the front-end, null checked in the back-end and returned if it does happen to be null. Since your front-end shouldn't allow to upload without a file you can safely return in the back-end. Someone likely tried to get around the validation in those cases.

Comment: Yes, of course I didn't mean it shouldn't be handled safely in the backend. But the backend should be able to consider this a "coding error in the front end", not a valid request.

Comment: Thank you alot for all the comments! In the end you were right FIldor with the fact that it shouldnt be even available until the picture is selected, so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't work when not selecting any file, try changing 
`var formFile = fileUpload.FormFile;`

To:

```
var formFile = fileUpload.FormFile;
if (formFile is null) return;

... rest of code
```

Comment: This perfectly worked!
didnt know there is a different between "If(formFIle == null)" and "if(formFIle is null)"
THANK YOU!